# Does the Guardian's Range stat affect the guardian pet's range, or the towers' range boost amount?

Tags: dungeon-defenders

Just beat it with my monk, and the language isn't clear — is investing in the guardian pet stat *guardian's range* going to enhance the range at which the little pet reaches out to boost towers, or will it enhance how much range boost the towers he can reach will receive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It will increase the range at which the pet reaches out to boost towers.**

The other Guardians also have a guardian range stat although their effects are to increase stats other than tower range (damage, attack speed, and resistance).

There should be a second stat you can invest points into that increases the effect that the guardian has on a tower if it is within range. For the Apprentice Guardian, that stat was right beside the guardian range stat.

Comment: my monk guardian does not have another 'special' stat... looking at someone's apprentice guardian I saw this stat and another which prompted the question.

Comment: @Maslow: It looks like it has both... maybe this is a different pet? http://i11.photobucket.com/albums/a157/Skeeterlite/monkguard2.jpg

Comment: mine does not, perhaps it is bugged =(

Comment: @Maslow no, its not a bug, some guardian pets simply don't have the range modifier, its not guarenteed to be there

Comment: Aye, to confirm, the pets you get at the end have a bit of the random mixed in with them.

Comment: @yx - it is a bug if the range modifier is the only thing there, with no stat for it to actually change on the towers it has in range, yes?

Comment: @Maslow yes, if that's the case then that's probably a bug.